# Converting int[] to boolean[] in Java based on whether a number is even (true) or not (false)

Tags: java, arrays, java-8, type-conversion, boolean

I am trying to convert an array containing int data type to an array containing boolean data type.
My method must be able to check whether the number is even or not and then store it as "true" if even or otherwise "false". The return type must a boolean array. **How do I do this?** The code I wrote apparenty doesn't work and I do not really understand why. Actually the error I get is *ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 12 out of bounds for length 6* (my original array has indeed 6 elements). Can someone please tell me why? I am using Java 8.

```
 public static boolean[] evenNumbers ( int[] array){
            boolean[] array1= new boolean[array.length];
            for (int i: array) {
                if(array[i]%2==0){
                    array5[i]=true;
                }
            }
            return array5;
        }
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: `array5` doesn't even exist here.

Comment: `i` is not the index, but the value... don't use `foreach` in this situation.

Answer (score 4):

In your loop, `i` is the element’s *value*, not its *index*, and so is likely to not be a valid index.

Change your *foreach* loop to a conventional `for` loop:

```
boolean[] result = new boolean[array.length];
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)  {
    result[i] = array[i]%2==0;
}
return result;
```

Answer (score 1):

> Can someone please tell me why?

In the *for* loop

```
for (int i: array) {
```

you're not using the indices, but the elements.

Use the traditional *for* instead, **as foreach was meant to hide the iterator.**

```
for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A stream-based solution (though returning `Boolean[]`) would be:

```java
public static Boolean[] evenNumbers ( int... array) {
    return IntStream.range(0, array.length)
                    .mapToObj(i -> array[i] % 2 == 0)
                    .toArray(Boolean[]::new);
}
```

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(evenNumbers(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 5, 3, 1, 2)));
```

Output:

```
[false, true, false, true, false, true, false, false, false, true]
```

Comment: or `Arrays.stream(array).mapToObj(j -> j % 2 == 0).toArray(Boolean[]::new)`